# Why doesn't g++ link with the dynamic library I create?

Tags: c++, g++, dynamic-linking, ld

I've been trying to make some applications which all rely on the same library, and dynamic libraries were my first thought: So I began writing the "Library":

```
/* ThinFS.h */

class FileSystem {
public:
    static void create_container(string file_name); //Creates a new container 
};

/* ThinFS.cpp */
#include "ThinFS.h"
void FileSystem::create_container(string file_name) {
     cout<<"Seems like I am going to create a new file called "<<file_name.c_str()<<endl;
}
```

I then compile the "Library"

```
g++ -shared -fPIC FileSystem.cpp -o ThinFS.o
```

I then quickly wrote a file that uses the Library:

```
#include "ThinFS.h"
int main() {
    FileSystem::create_container("foo");
    return (42);
}
```

I then tried to compile that with

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -lThinFS
```

But it won't compile with the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lThinFS
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I think I'm missing something very obvious, please help me :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`-lfoo` looks for a library called `libfoo.a` (static) or `libfoo.so` (shared) in the current library path, so to create the library, you need to use `g++ -shared -fPIC FileSystem.cpp -o libThinFS.so`

Comment: Thanks, the lib was missing in the front (.o instead of .so was just a typo) :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
g++ main.cpp -L. -l:ThinFS
```

The use of "colon" will use the library name as it is, rather requiring a prefix of "lib"

Answer (score 3):

the name of the output file should be **libThinFS.so**, e.g.

```
g++ -shared -fPIC FileSystem.cpp -o libThinFS.so
```

Answer (score 2):

The result of `g++ -shared -fPIC FileSystem.cpp` is not an object file, so it should not end with `.o`. Also, shared libraries should be named `libXXX.so`. Rename the library and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article.

http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LibraryArchives-StaticAndDynamic.html

A good resource on how to build different types of libraries. It also describes how and where to use them.